# Merging two DataFrame using a range of columns (Right on ID and left on multiple IDs)

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation, vlookup

I want to create a dataset from two `df` using `id`. The problem is that on the second `df` , `id` is not located in a single column. The `id` value can be located in different columns.

```
merged=pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['id','month','year'], right_on=['id_name','id_surname','id_first_name', month','year'], how="left")
```

All the `id` variables are alphanumeric.

But I receive the error:

```
ValueError: len(right_on) must equal len(left_on)
```

Ideally, I would like to test if `id` is in one of the other three column `ids` , and merge accordingly on that column.  Maybe some sort of vlookup() function (from excel) to allow to look up a key value within a range in a table array. Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot join on different number of keys. You will need to create a column for the second dataframe which will contain all the IDs you need.  
You can also try to do three joins consecutively, one time for each of the 'id_name','id_surname','id_first_name' columns of the second df. 
Please provide a sample of your dataframes, so that I can assist more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have the following two dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1, 2, 3],
        "month": ["Jan", "Mar", "Apr"],
        "year": ["2022", "2020", "2021"],
        "column_A": ["test", "test_", "test__"]
    }
)


df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id_name": [1, np.NaN, np.NaN],
        "id_surname": [np.NaN, 2, np.NaN],
        "id_first_name": [np.NaN, np.NaN, 3],
        "month": ["Jan", "Mar", "Apr"],
        "year": ["2022", "2020", "2021"],
        "column_B": ["check", "check_", "check__"]
    }
)
```

The second dataframe will be:

```
   id_name  id_surname  id_first_name month  year column_B
0      1.0         NaN            NaN   Jan  2022   check
1      NaN         2.0            NaN   Mar  2020   check_
2      NaN         NaN            3.0   Apr  2021   check__
```

You can create a new column `id` for the second dataframe by keeping all non NaN values from the three columns `id_name, id_surname, id_first_name`. Starting from the `id_name` column and filling its NaNs with non Nans values of `id_surname` and then filling the remaining NaNs with the non-NaNs of the `id_first_name`. The code to do that is:

```
df2["id"] = df2["id_name"].fillna(df2["id_surname"]).fillna(df2["id_first_name"])
```

which will create the column `id` for the `df2`:

```
   id_name  id_surname  id_first_name month  year column_B   id
0      1.0         NaN            NaN   Jan  2022   check    1.0
1      NaN         2.0            NaN   Mar  2020   check_   2.0
2      NaN         NaN            3.0   Apr  2021   check__  3.0
```

Finally, you can merge by:

```
merged = pd.merge(
    df1,
    df2,
    left_on=["id", "month", "year"],
    right_on=["id", "month", "year"],
    how="left",
)
```

and the result will be:

```
   id month  year column_A  id_name  id_surname  id_first_name column_B
0   1   Jan  2022     test      1.0         NaN            NaN   check
1   2   Mar  2020    test_      NaN         2.0            NaN   check_
2   3   Apr  2021   test__      NaN         NaN            3.0   check__
```

Comment: Pandas fillna function was what I needed. I hadn't even thought of that!